# variables 'y' and 'x' used in loop condition not modified in loop body - help, previous answers have not helped

Tags: c, cs50

Please could someone help with this - I am completely new to coding and just started the cs50 course, I really am struggling to understand most of the course. I've scraped through this lab but I keep getting this error message "population.c:22:17: error: variables 'y' and 'x' used in loop condition not modified in loop body [-Werror,-Wfor-loop-analysis]
for (n = 0; y < x; n++)". I've tried to look through similar questions on here and apply those solutions, none of which have worked. Could someone please help?

My code is below

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // TODO: Prompt for start size
    int x,y,n ;
    do
    {
        x = get_int("Start size: ");
    }
    while ( x < 9);

    // TODO: Prompt for end size
    do
    {
        y = get_int("end size: ");
    }
    while (y < x);

    // TODO: Calculate number of years until we reach threshold
    for (n = 0; y < x; n++)

    {
    n = x + x/3 - x/4;
    }
    printf("Years: %i", n);

    // TODO: Print number of years
}
```

Comment: As the error tells you - `n = 0; y < x; n++` does not make sense - `y` is never changed in the loop body, so it most likely this will either be an infinite loop (when `y < x`) or the code will never execute (when `y >= x`). Also please add information about the goal of the exercise.

Comment: It means you have not changed either x or y inside the loop (which form the condition of the loop). That'd mean your loop runs infinitely many times or doesn't run at all. If you can tell what you're trying to achieve, maybe I might help you in that direction.

Comment: But what part of the compiler's warning don't you understand? The loop depends on the comparison `y < x`. If it is initially true, the loop body will be executed. After that the condition is re-evaluated and the loop makes another iteration or terminates, depending on the result. But... if the loop body does not modify `x` nor `y` then the comparison result will not change, hence the loop either will not run even once (so it's useless) or it will iterate forever (so it's most probably useless).

Comment: Please read [ask] and [open letter to students](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). When you post a homework related question, it should include a copy of the assignment, verbatim. We can't help you learn your lessons, if we don't know what they are.

Comment: May be you should describe in words what your progam should do, define its purpose. Then describe a solution of the problem, that is what calculations should be done to achieve the goal. And only then start translating the soultion to a source code. I suspect you skipped some important step either in the first or in the middle phase, which led you to the code presented above.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (n = 0; y < x; n++)
{
n = x + x/3 - x/4;
}
```

This loop keeps executing while y is less than x.  However, the only variable that changes inside the loop is n.  x and y remain unchanged.

So either this loop will never run, or it will run forever.

Comment: so how do I fix it? Do I remove the y<x?

Comment: Fix it by using the correct loop condition.  I don't know what the code is supposed to do, so I don't know what the correct condition is...

Answer (score 0):

It would really help to know what the goal of the exercise is.

What we know from what you’ve posted is that the initial value of `x` must be greater than or equal to 9 and that the initial value of `y` must be greater than or equal to `x`.

Based on that alone, we know your loop will never execute since `y < x` will not be true.  Based on the calculation involving `x` and the comment about reaching a threshold, I *strongly* suspect your loop is supposed to be written as

```
for ( n = 0; x < y; n++ )
{
  x = x + x/3 - x/4;
}
```